# USB Server Logilink not working on VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to run USB Server on a virtual machine (virtualBox 3.1.8) However the application shows 'no USB Server found'.

I've ran the USB Server application from a windows 7 machine and it works fine.

Is there any obvious mistakes I'm making?

I can also ping the USB Server from the virtual machine(VM is running XP).

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VM Network adapter should have been 'Bridged' not 'NAT'. Issue resolved.